# PHP - reordering using loop

Tags: php

I have three variables:

```
$title_order    = 1;
$image_order    = 2;
$content_order  = 3;
```

and user can rearrange/reorder above variable, Like:

```
$title_order    = 2;
$image_order    = 1;
$content_order  = 3;
```

Now, as per this variable I want to reorder below HTML

```
<h1><?php title() ?></h1>
<figure><?php thumbnail() ?></figure>
<details><?php thumbnail() ?></details>
```

how to show this as per variable number, like:

```
<figure><?php thumbnail() ?></figure> // show image 1st if $image_orer    = 1;
<h1><?php title() ?></h1> // show h1 in 2nd if $title_order    = 2;
<details><?php thumbnail() ?></details> // show h1 3rd if $content_order    = 3;
```

please note user can set variable to anything between 1,2 and 3.

so please tell me how do i achieve this.

Comment: what?? read question, you'll know the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$result = '';
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; ++$i) {
    switch ($i) {
        case $title_order:
            $result .= '<h1>' . title() . '</h1>';
            break;

        case $image_order:
            $result .= '<figure>' . thumbnail() . '</figure>';
            break;

        case $content_order:
            $result .= '<details>' . thumbnail() . '</details>';
            break;
    }
}

echo $result;
```